# How to link JavaScript file to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I am creating a very simple HTML file and I am trying to link it to a JavaScript file so that the text changes when I click on it.

I have copied it almost entirely from W3 and it works when I place the javascript code within the HTML script tags, but when I try to source it using the script tags (see the first example below) I am not able to get the JavaScript file to link to the HTML.

Any help you can give me is appreciated. I am currently using Visual Studio Code to do this if that gives any hints as to what I am doing wrong.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>TextChange</title>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This example uses the HTML DOM to assign an "onclick" event to a p element.</p>
    <p id="demo">Click me.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}
```

Alternate HTML that works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>TextChange</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This example uses the HTML DOM to assign an "onclick" event to a p element.</p>
    <p id="demo">Click me.</p>
    <script>

document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I render the HTML and view the source and click on the .js extension, I am able to view the javascript file. Despite this, the text that I want to change when I click on it does not change if I click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS file is included before the element, so `getElementById()` returns null.

Move it after the element, or make it wait for the document's loaded event.

Answer (score 0):

Your script tag must be on the bottom of your html code (before the closure of `<body>` tag) so your javascript can use and detect the different DOM elements after they get rendered :

```
<html>
  <body>

  <!-- your code here -->

   <script src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: or wrapped in an onload handler